# Syncing online database data with local sqlite database android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-internet

I couldn't really find information on this particular problem anywhere even though I know there is a lot of questions and documentation on sqlite so sorry if this is a duplicate.

Anyways, I'm developing an app which logs a user in and performs actions on a mysql database on my website via php scripts. But so that the user doesn't have to wait for a web response for every button they press/every activity launch, I have a sqlite database attached to the app which stores the live information as the app is being used (It uses GPS tracking so this data is stored as well as other things).

I suppose my question is, how much should I store locally to be uploaded later? Should I try and do everything locally after initially logging the user in and just uploading/syncing the data in the user's profile onPause() or something and make use of the lifecycle? Or should I do the opposite and try and do everything live online and get rid of the local sqlite database altogether?

Just wondering if anyone has had experience with this kind of situation and what conclusions they came to.

Thanks for your time,

Infinitifizz

Answer (score 0):

There are some `sqlite3-rdiff` tools for syncing SQLite databases at [mobigroup](http://sqlite.mobigroup.ru/wiki?name=sqlite3-rdiff)

Comment: Thanks but I don't mean I want to upload the whole database file to the server because it's not my server and so I am just using a provided mysql database. What I am asking is what is best practice and what compromises do I have to make for best practice?